# Default git to use --no-color in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell

Is there any way to default git commands to use `--no-color` at a Powershell command prompt? It's too hard to read dark red on a black background and would be nice if it wasn't necessary to type `--no-color` so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To globally default to using *no* colors, set the [`color.ui`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorui) configuration  setting globally to `never` or `false`:

```
git config --global color.ui never
```

*Caveat*: Command(-family) specific color configuration settings exist too (e.g. `color.status`), which override `color.ui`, if set.

To unset later, use `git config --global --unset color.ui`